# Retrieving only valid values from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to retrieve only the values that are not empty from a Json to Javascript.

This is the code:

```
var words = [

{word: '', phrase: 'phrase1', url: 'url.1'},
{word: 'word2', phrase: '', url: 'url.2'},
{word: '', phrase: 'phrase3', url: 'url.3'},
{word: 'word4', phrase: 'phrase4', url: ''}

];
    var factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var randomWordsIT = words[factIndex];
    var selectWordFromRandom = randomWordsIT.word;

 alert(selectWordFromRandom);
```

For example, if (selectWordFromRandom.isEmpty){random again}.

Thanks!

Comment: if word='' then you need to make it wordn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a while loop until your *selectWordFromRandom* variable becomes populated.

```
var selectWordFromRandom = '';
while (selectWordFromRandom == ''){
    var factIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    var randomWordsIT = words[factIndex];
    selectWordFromRandom = randomWordsIT.word;
}

alert(selectWordFromRandom);
```

An alternative way would be to pre-filter your array to remove all empty values.